# Как отобразить несколько строк из mysql в список?

Tags: php, mysql, telegram-bot

Пишу Телеграм-бот

Имеется таблица

```
   name   |  sum | rain
Название1 |  153 | NTS
Название2 |  145 | 
Название3 |  142 | NTS
Название4 |  135 | NTS
Название5 |  178 |
```

Так я отбираю строки с одинаковым значением, допустим на ответ у меня SQL находит 2-3 строки, может больше.

```
SELECT `name`, `sum` FROM `buyd` WHERE `rain`='NTS'
```

Мне нужно отправить форматированное сообщение такого вида

```
Название1  153 
Название3  145 
Название4  178
```

Присваиваю перменные

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `name`, `sum` FROM `base` WHERE `rain`='".$rain."'");
$array = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$sum = $array[1];
$name = $array[0];
```

Хочу что бы одна переменная выводила в такой формат, если это вообще возможно

Вывожу в ответ

```
apiRequest("sendMessage", array('chat_id' => $chat_id, "text" => "$name $sum"}
```

Comment: Покажите, как вы выводите в какой-нибудь формат

Comment: @splash58 Дополнил вопрос

Comment: `while($array = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { echo $array[0] . "\t". $array[1]."\n"  }`

Comment: Здесь нет вывода. Вы просто присваиваете значения двум переменным

Comment: @AntonShchyrov прошу прощения, не так понял, еще дополнил

Comment: @АртурКабиров Вы хотите прям несколько строк в одну переменную? Тогда в  цикле `$str .=  $array[0] . ' ' . $array[1]."\n"`

Comment: @splash58 А если не в одну переменную как вывести их в такой список? Что бы все вышли которые совпадают.

Comment: Теперь осталось узнать, что делает функция `apiRequest()` и что она делает с передваемыми параметрами

Comment: я ж вам написал while цикл чуть повыше. Посмотрите, что он покажет

Comment: @AntonShchyrov это бот телеграм, человек пишет значение rain, бот берет с базы все значения которые есть, и отправляет человеку ответ в виде сообщения в со списком

Comment: @splash58 добавил это значение и отправил боту сообщение в логе вот что _[24-Nov-2017 19:33:19 Europe/Moscow] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE) in /backup/home/gswvtsit/public_html/index.php on line 221_
**221** строка имеет текст `$spisok = while($array = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { $array[0] . " ". $array[1]."\n" }`

Comment: Это на php. Его бы исполнить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) сообщения в телеграме может иметь базовое форматирование. В частности, можно посылать моноширинный текст. Вот его и нужно использовать

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `name`, `sum` FROM `base` WHERE `rain`='".$rain."'");
$msg = '<pre>';
while ($array = mysql_fetch_array($query))
  $msg .= sprintf("%-10s %5s\n", $array[0], $array[1]);
$msg .= '</pre>';
apiRequest("sendMessage", array('chat_id' => $chat_id, "text" => $msg));
```

Comment: Все спасибо большое, разобрался, очень помогли!

Comment: а можно как то еще этот же массив использовать, для того что бы вывести инлайн кнопки с этими же текстами? Сколько строк, столько и кнопок, вида `[key1], [key2]`